# Ограничить AppDomain директорией

Tags: c#, appdomain

Здравствуйте!
Есть структура папок:

```
-Common
   common1.dll
   common2.dll
   -Plugins
      +[plugin1]
      +[plugin2]
```

При создании AppDomain, BaseDirectory указывается "Common", чтобы можно было загрузить общие библиотеки без копирования в каждый плагин.
Можно ли сделать доступ только к папке "Common/Plugins/Plugin1" для AppDomain (плагин первый)  при работе с [файлами\папками(поиск, запись, чтение)]?

Спасибо!

Comment: Не уверен, но попробуйте поискать тут: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms972968%28en-us%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону `AppDomain.SetupInformation`. Не рекомендуется менять пути для поиска папок через `AppDomain.BaseDirecory`, лучше делать это при создании домена. Там есть несколько свойств для поиска папок, в частности, `PrivateBinPath`.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы было разрешение на доступ папок *"Common"* и *"Common/Plugins/Plugin1"*. **PrivateBinPath** устанавливает дополнительный поиск сборок, если не смог найти в директории **BaseDirectory**. То есть получается, я расширяю доступ видимости папок... а мне нужно ограничение...